# MS Sql Msg 8152

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have an array of values for the where clause. I have following and I am getting msg 8152 at line 3 error.

Update: I added varchar(50) and now it's working. The following code is now good. Thanks everyone for participating.

```
declare @jobName table (jobname varchar(50))
insert @jobName(jobname) 
values('2F4A08BF-3535-47EA-B3B8-8DDE7D46043E'),
('48720008-CC4E-4F67-A9D7-0C7F29991214'),
('919C8713-9ED0-4ECC-8880-7335C420E7DB'),
('9A38C056-9DC4-44EF-895B-9325690F7300'),
('A849630B-D898-4444-80BD-B0CBADAEA6DD'),
('BF867B49-8BB1-49C0-B67D-6DEE77EB0421'),
('BFB35F27-FCC5-40A9-B57B-E1EFB06BDB6A'),
('D6E2EA84-939A-401C-8B36-BE5BDFBE1F91'),
('F5A6DE42-91B5-408C-A707-BD412A695683');


SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs]
  --where name like '2F4A08BF-3535-47EA-B3B8-8DDE7D46043E' or '48720008-CC4E-4F67-A9D7-0C7F29991214'
  where name in (select jobname from @jobName)
  order by job_id asc
```

Comment: define varchar with length otherwise it's length will be default 1, which won't hold the full string and truncate it to only one single character.

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to varchar(50) and it worked . Thanks Siyual

Comment: Or  `... table (jobname sysname)` as *sysjobs.name* is a `sysname` not a `varchar`.

Answer (score 0):

use `IN` clause

```
where name in ('2F4A08BF-3535-47EA-B3B8-8DDE7D46043E','48720008-CC4E-4F67-A9D7-0C7F29991214')
And name in (select jobname from @jobName)
```

Not sure why you want `name = 'aaa' OR 'bbbb'` condition when the value is already present in `@jobName` table

Also default length `varchar` will be `1` so change it to proper length

```
declare @jobName table (jobname varchar(500))
```

Answer (score 0):

declare @jobName table (jobname **varchar**) : Error here.

The type is wrong, use varchar(80) instead of just varchar.

Answer (score 0):

Change your table declaration like this:

```
declare @jobName table (jobname varchar(100))  -- 100 or something
```

You have to define varchar with length otherwise it's length will be default 1, which won't hold the full string and truncate it to only one single character